# Control the element propery of textarea by value of radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am just wondering if I could get some advice or help in javascript. I am a beginner in html , jquery and javascript. I am trying  to control the element property of the jquery text area using java script based on the selected radio button value I get the code of the textarea by viewing the page source of my page. My Text Area is set Mandatory=true by default in element propertY I am just wondering if I could make the Mandatory false depend in the value of radio button. I can succesfully get the value of my radio button but still not control the element propert of text area

Code for radio button to get the value but not working for element property

```js
     $(document).ready(function(){ 
         $('input[type=radio][name=Rank]').change(function() {
         if (this.value == 'Vip') {
            alert("Vip");
            $('#Comment').prop('required',false);//I want to set mandatory false
        }
        else if (this.value == 'not') {
         $('#Comment').prop('required',true);//I want to set mandatory true
        }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-cell"  element-class="org.joget.apps.form.lib.TextArea" element-property="{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;Comment&quot;,&quot;workflowVariable&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;readonlyLabel&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;cols&quot;:&quot;60&quot;,&quot;validator&quot;:{&quot;className&quot;:&quot;org.joget.apps.form.lib.DefaultValidator&quot;,&quot;properties&quot;:{&quot;message&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;custom-regex&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;mandatory&quot;:&quot;true&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;&quot;}},&quot;value&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Comment&quot;,&quot;readonly&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;rows&quot;:&quot;3&quot;}" >
    <label class="label">Comment <span class="form-cell-validator">*</span></label>
        <textarea id="Comment" name="Comment" cols="60"  rows="3"  ></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: And what isn't working?

Comment: not working i can submit the form even not filling the textareaaa if I am not a vip or a vip either there is no validation

Comment: Please share your full HTML markup, and make a minimal, working example demonstrating your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally set required to false should work but you can try below

```js
     $(document).ready(function(){ 
         $('input[type=radio][name=Rank]').change(function() {
         if (this.value == 'Vip') {
            alert("Vip");
            $('#Comment').removeAttr('required');
        } else if (this.value == 'not') {
         $('#Comment').prop('required',true);//I want to set mandatory true
        }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I tried it its not working I really appreciate your help please see my div madatory true thank you really appreciate